# Xrdp/openbox allocates 15 GB of hard disk after some days

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, openbox, xrdp

I use xrdp running openbox on a Debian 11 virtual machine that does computing and runs several days. I access the vm via Windows RDP.

I wondered that ~ 15 GB are allocated on the hard disk somehow by X/xrdp/openbox (and tint2 as taskbar). After some days of usage and stopping all the computing apps besides a vanilla running openbox there was a additional hard disk usage of ~15 GB as difference between `df` and `du`. I could not find out where these additional 15 GB were used (using `ncdu`).

After I log out from openbox there are 15 GB more free space on the hard disk said by `df` within a second.

Do you have a clue what is going on and how to fix it? It sounds like a memory leak on the hard disk (and not the RAM).

Comment: It's probably keeping open a file descriptor of a deleted file.